# Adding Rust (programming language) syntax to Notepad++?

Tags: windows, notepad++, rust

I would like to use Notepad++ as I learn Rust. Is it possible to do this? If it is, how do I do it?

Comment: I'm not familiar to rust, but try with this: https://gist.github.com/heimp/6502384

Comment: A simple internet search for  "notepad++ rust" returns at least two links at the top with code that say they do exactly what you ask.

Comment: @Shepmaster : But how do you add it to?

Comment: @Nehru One of the options [gives steps for using/adding it](https://github.com/pfalabella/Rust-notepadplusplus#readme).

Answer (score 8):

You can use Notepad++ to edit the source files, nothing else is needed.

If you want syntax coloring, [a syntax file is available](https://github.com/pfalabella/Rust-notepadplusplus), the README has an explanation on how to import the XML file.

For compiling and running the code, you can just use the command line.

I don't think there is a plugin for code completion yet, but it could be implemented with [racer](https://github.com/phildawes/racer).

I like Notepad++, but there are more plugins for Sublime Text, Atom, or VS Code. You can also use Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Rust is supported by Notepad++ since v7.5 (2017) ([change list](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/wiki/Changes#75)). Most of the themes like `Styler.xml`, `DarkModeDefault.xml`, etc., supports rust text highlighting.
Just change the themes from `Settings > Style Configurator`.