# Configuring Visual Studio Code for Rust

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

Problems in the source code found during compilation in the Visual Studio Code are marked by underlining the suspicious code with a thick red line, sometimes many code lines. This makes the code difficult to read. Below is an example. There is one erroneous character in the code, but it is quite hard to find it in this output.

[image]

**Is there any way to get rid of this underlining?**

Comment: Please ask one question per SO question.

Comment: You requested people to violate SO rules by providing answer to an invalid question in the comments. I rolled back your edit. If you think your questions are good, please ask them as **separate** questions. For example, at least the inlay hints one is duplicate. I could've closed it if it was a separate question, but not now.

Comment: @Chayim Friedman: I've changed and hopefully improved the question. I think it can be reopened.

Comment: I believe this happens when the function signature and function body don't agree on the return type (caused my an errant `?` perhaps), though I agree that highlighting the entire body is detrimental.

Comment: To clarify: are you using the Rust-Analyzer extension? or something else?

Comment: I wonder what it looks like if you pull this up in Notepad ++ .. it seems to support so many languages now.
(citation - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34435031/adding-rust-programming-language-syntax-to-notepad )

Comment: @kmdreko: Yes, I use the Rust-Analyzer extension. Actually I've downloaded quite a few extensions: Rust Development Extension Pack, Rust Extension Pack, Rust Syntax and some more, but these should not affect the code presentation. Rust-Analyzer is included alone and inside the two extension packs.

Comment: @kmdreko: Yes, here the error is the question mark. But all errors and warnings give the display like this.

Comment: @easleyfixed: Yes, it looks good in Notepad++. Notepad apparently recognizes the syntax and displays strings in "" and comments in color. I could skip Visual Studio Code and use Notepad++ and cargo from the command line. But Visual Studio Code does some things for me for free. The above display problem should have some solution.

Comment: I feel you there,  well I hope you can find a pure VB solution.

Comment: "but these should not affect the code presentation" I would definitely suspect multiple packages trying to do the same thing would stomp on each others toes. Uninstall everything but rust-analyzer and see if it works.

Comment: @Colonel Thirty Two: sorry, I wasn't clear enough. Extensions such as Rust-Analyzer, Rust Development Extension Pack, and Rust Extension Pack have a significant impact on code presentation. Other extensions I have, e.g., for test, Git, and cargo, should not affect the code presentation. I can try the approach of removing extensions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by **uninstalling** some extensions. Currently, I only have the extensions rust-analyzer and CodeLLDB, and everything seems to work fine.

The lesson from this case is that the VSC extensions for Rust do not always improve your environment, and you should be careful with them.